# tty1 misbehavior

Tags: gnome, 18.04, tty

As I was told previously, Ubuntu 18.04 launches six consoles tty1-6. Consoles tty3-6 work pretty welle for me. My desktop environment is at tty2 by default.

tty1 is inconsistent for me however. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> from a tty that doesn't contain a desktop environment it shows me a GNOME login screen, but when I press it from my desktop environment, it sometimes stops sending a signal to my monitor (the monitor stays black receiving no signal until I switch to another tty) and sometimes shows me a console that isn't blank like another tty's and looks like this. (this is not my  screenshot, my console just looks the same, but the text may differ).

[image]

This console doesn't take any input, though, but it seems to contain information about what is going on with my PC, so I'd like to always be able to access it.

Thus, my question is what is this black screen with the green OKs, and why can I also see GNOME login screen or just nothing (no signal) instead?

P.S. I can sometimes see it for a fraction of a second when shutting my PC down.